# error running ionic start tabs demo

Tags: android, ionic-framework

The error description is: [image]

> Command failed: F:\Git\cmd\git.EXE submodule update -q --init
>   --recursive    fatal: 'submodule' appears to be a git command, but we were not   able to execute it. Maybe git-submodule is broken?'

Comment: does any body konw it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug, check this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17460).